# Problems setting up dx12

Tags: directx

I'm following the Frank Luna directX12 book, I have installed the windows 10 SDK etc but now, when I compile any project from his demo they wont build. Error I am getting is Cannot open source file  which I have never had a problem including before I installed windows 10 SDK, any suggestions? If any more info is needed let me know